# Post grafana dashboard to particular folder

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I am trying to use the grafana API to post dashboards to a specific folder. Using the following command, I can see the folder ID's for all folders in my grafana:

```
curl -X GET http://<username>:<password>@localhost:3000/api/folders?limit=200

[{"id":9,"uid":"6m0M3AZZk","title":"Apps"},{"id":38,"uid":"jEJ5aSVZz","title":"Cluster_Health"},{"id":31,"uid":"vsmJ2dGZz","title":"CPU by App"},{"id":51,"uid":"Fx9ajQXWz","title":"Data Pipeline"},{"id":6,"uid":"dYFMMhZWz","title":"home"},{"id":19,"uid":"qDwG6yWZz","title":"Node_Health"},{"id":18,"uid":"37pWeyWZk","title":"Pending_Data"},{"id":44,"uid":"nreWbxfWz","title":"Prod"},{"id":13,"uid":"PYzEBYZWk","title":"Services"},{"id":27,"uid":"byVe4IMWk","title":"API"}]
```

Now, I would like to post a dashboard to my Services folder (id 13). However, when I make my request, this dashboard is always going to the General folder. I am using a python script to make my request:

```
def post_dashboard(filepath):
    with open(filepath, "r") as fin:
        data = json.loads(fin.read())
    data = json.dumps(data)
    response = requests.post("http://localhost:3000/api/dashboards/db", headers=headers_raw, data=data)
    print(response.json())
    print(response.status_code)
```

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{"dashboard": {
  "annotations": {
    "list": [
      {
        "builtIn": 1,
        "datasource": "-- Grafana --",
        "enable": true,
        "hide": true,
        "iconColor": "rgba(0, 211, 255, 1)",
        "name": "Annotations & Alerts",
        "type": "dashboard"
      }
    ]
  },
  "editable": true,
  "gnetId": null,
  "graphTooltip": 0,
  "id": null,
  "iteration": 1593098750052,
  "links": [],
  "panels": [
    {
      "aliasColors": {},
      "bars": false,
      "dashLength": 10,
      "dashes": false,
      "datasource": "Prometheus-1",
      "description": "The amount of CPU taken up by redis from top command",
      "fill": 0,
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 8,
        "w": 24,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
      },
      "id": 10,
      "legend": {
        "avg": false,
        "current": false,
        "max": false,
        "min": false,
        "show": true,
        "total": false,
        "values": false
      },
      "lines": true,
      "linewidth": 1,
      "links": [],
      "nullPointMode": "null",
      "percentage": false,
      "pointradius": 2,
      "points": false,
      "renderer": "flot",
      "seriesOverrides": [],
      "spaceLength": 10,
      "stack": false,
      "steppedLine": false,
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "app_cpu{node_type=\"process\", cluster_id=~\"$cluster\", app_name=~\".*redisserver.*\"}",
          "format": "time_series",
          "intervalFactor": 1,
          "legendFormat": "{{ host_name }}",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "thresholds": [],
      "timeFrom": null,
      "timeRegions": [],
      "timeShift": null,
      "title": "CPU Used",
      "tooltip": {
        "shared": true,
        "sort": 2,
        "value_type": "individual"
      },
      "type": "graph",
      "xaxis": {
        "buckets": null,
        "mode": "time",
        "name": null,
        "show": true,
        "values": []
      },
      "yaxes": [
        {
          "format": "short",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        },
        {
          "format": "short",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        }
      ],
      "yaxis": {
        "align": false,
        "alignLevel": null
      }
    },
    {
      "aliasColors": {},
      "bars": false,
      "dashLength": 10,
      "dashes": false,
      "datasource": "Prometheus-1",
      "description": "The current amount of memory redis is consuming",
      "fill": 0,
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 9,
        "w": 12,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 8
      },
      "id": 2,
      "legend": {
        "avg": false,
        "current": false,
        "max": false,
        "min": false,
        "show": true,
        "total": false,
        "values": false
      },
      "lines": true,
      "linewidth": 1,
      "links": [],
      "nullPointMode": "null",
      "percentage": false,
      "pointradius": 2,
      "points": false,
      "renderer": "flot",
      "seriesOverrides": [],
      "spaceLength": 10,
      "stack": false,
      "steppedLine": false,
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "redis_mem_used{cluster_id=~\"$cluster\"}",
          "format": "time_series",
          "intervalFactor": 1,
          "legendFormat": "{{ node }}",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "thresholds": [],
      "timeFrom": null,
      "timeRegions": [],
      "timeShift": null,
      "title": "Redis Memory Used",
      "tooltip": {
        "shared": true,
        "sort": 2,
        "value_type": "individual"
      },
      "type": "graph",
      "xaxis": {
        "buckets": null,
        "mode": "time",
        "name": null,
        "show": true,
        "values": []
      },
      "yaxes": [
        {
          "format": "decbytes",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        },
        {
          "format": "short",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        }
      ],
      "yaxis": {
        "align": false,
        "alignLevel": null
      }
    },
    {
      "aliasColors": {},
      "bars": false,
      "dashLength": 10,
      "dashes": false,
      "datasource": "Prometheus-1",
      "description": "The maximum amount of memory that redis has used",
      "fill": 0,
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 9,
        "w": 12,
        "x": 12,
        "y": 8
      },
      "id": 4,
      "legend": {
        "avg": false,
        "current": false,
        "max": false,
        "min": false,
        "show": true,
        "total": false,
        "values": false
      },
      "lines": true,
      "linewidth": 1,
      "links": [],
      "nullPointMode": "null",
      "percentage": false,
      "pointradius": 2,
      "points": false,
      "renderer": "flot",
      "seriesOverrides": [],
      "spaceLength": 10,
      "stack": false,
      "steppedLine": false,
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "redis_mem_peak{cluster_id=~\"$cluster\"}",
          "format": "time_series",
          "intervalFactor": 1,
          "legendFormat": "{{ node }}",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "thresholds": [],
      "timeFrom": null,
      "timeRegions": [],
      "timeShift": null,
      "title": "Redis Peak Memory",
      "tooltip": {
        "shared": true,
        "sort": 2,
        "value_type": "individual"
      },
      "type": "graph",
      "xaxis": {
        "buckets": null,
        "mode": "time",
        "name": null,
        "show": true,
        "values": []
      },
      "yaxes": [
        {
          "format": "decbytes",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        },
        {
          "format": "short",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        }
      ],
      "yaxis": {
        "align": false,
        "alignLevel": null
      }
    },
    {
      "aliasColors": {},
      "bars": false,
      "dashLength": 10,
      "dashes": false,
      "datasource": "Prometheus-1",
      "description": "The amount of memory used by the LUA engine inside of redis",
      "fill": 0,
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 8,
        "w": 12,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 17
      },
      "id": 6,
      "legend": {
        "avg": false,
        "current": false,
        "max": false,
        "min": false,
        "show": true,
        "total": false,
        "values": false
      },
      "lines": true,
      "linewidth": 1,
      "links": [],
      "nullPointMode": "null",
      "percentage": false,
      "pointradius": 2,
      "points": false,
      "renderer": "flot",
      "seriesOverrides": [],
      "spaceLength": 10,
      "stack": false,
      "steppedLine": false,
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "redis_mem_lua{cluster_id=~\"$cluster\"}",
          "format": "time_series",
          "intervalFactor": 1,
          "legendFormat": "{{ node }}",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "thresholds": [],
      "timeFrom": null,
      "timeRegions": [],
      "timeShift": null,
      "title": "LUA Mem Used",
      "tooltip": {
        "shared": true,
        "sort": 2,
        "value_type": "individual"
      },
      "type": "graph",
      "xaxis": {
        "buckets": null,
        "mode": "time",
        "name": null,
        "show": true,
        "values": []
      },
      "yaxes": [
        {
          "format": "decbytes",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        },
        {
          "format": "short",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        }
      ],
      "yaxis": {
        "align": false,
        "alignLevel": null
      }
    },
    {
      "aliasColors": {},
      "bars": false,
      "dashLength": 10,
      "dashes": false,
      "datasource": "Prometheus-1",
      "description": "The amount of memory used as observed by top",
      "fill": 0,
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 8,
        "w": 12,
        "x": 12,
        "y": 17
      },
      "id": 8,
      "legend": {
        "avg": false,
        "current": false,
        "max": false,
        "min": false,
        "show": true,
        "total": false,
        "values": false
      },
      "lines": true,
      "linewidth": 1,
      "links": [],
      "nullPointMode": "null",
      "percentage": false,
      "pointradius": 2,
      "points": false,
      "renderer": "flot",
      "seriesOverrides": [],
      "spaceLength": 10,
      "stack": false,
      "steppedLine": false,
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "redis_mem_rss{cluster_id=~\"$cluster\"}",
          "format": "time_series",
          "intervalFactor": 1,
          "legendFormat": "{{ node }}",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "thresholds": [],
      "timeFrom": null,
      "timeRegions": [],
      "timeShift": null,
      "title": "RSS Mem Used",
      "tooltip": {
        "shared": true,
        "sort": 2,
        "value_type": "individual"
      },
      "type": "graph",
      "xaxis": {
        "buckets": null,
        "mode": "time",
        "name": null,
        "show": true,
        "values": []
      },
      "yaxes": [
        {
          "format": "decbytes",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        },
        {
          "format": "short",
          "label": null,
          "logBase": 1,
          "max": null,
          "min": null,
          "show": true
        }
      ],
      "yaxis": {
        "align": false,
        "alignLevel": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "schemaVersion": 18,
  "style": "dark",
  "tags": [],
  "templating": {
    "list": [
      {
        "allValue": null,
        "current": {},
        "datasource": "Prometheus-1",
        "definition": "label_values(redis_mem_used, cluster_id)",
        "hide": 0,
        "includeAll": true,
        "label": null,
        "multi": true,
        "name": "cluster",
        "options": [],
        "query": "label_values(redis_mem_used, cluster_id)",
        "refresh": 1,
        "regex": "",
        "skipUrlSync": false,
        "sort": 0,
        "tagValuesQuery": "",
        "tags": [],
        "tagsQuery": "",
        "type": "query",
        "useTags": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "time": {
    "from": "now-6h",
    "to": "now"
  },
  "timepicker": {
    "refresh_intervals": [
      "5s",
      "10s",
      "30s",
      "1m",
      "5m",
      "15m",
      "30m",
      "1h",
      "2h",
      "1d"
    ],
    "time_options": [
      "5m",
      "15m",
      "1h",
      "6h",
      "12h",
      "24h",
      "2d",
      "7d",
      "30d"
    ]
  },
  "timezone": "",
  "title": "Redis",
  "uid": "rfdsk32",
  "folder": "Services",
  "folderTitle": "Services",
  "folderId": 13,
  "overwrite": true
 }
}
```

My grafana version is 6.2.0. I have used several references that say that folderId should be the controlling keyword for which folder a dashboard goes to.
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/dashboard/#create-update-dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used wrong payload structure:

```
{
  "dashboard": {
    ...
    "folderId": 13,
    "overwrite": true
  }
}
```

Correct structure is:

```
{
  "dashboard": {
    ...
  },
  "folderId": 13,
  "overwrite": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, this was indeed the problem.